# Filtering Live json Stream on linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jq

I have live raw json stream data from the virtual radar server I'm using.

I use Netcat to fetch the data and jq to save it on my kali linux. using the following command.

> nc 127.0.0.1 30006 | jq > A7.json

But i want to filter specific content from the data stream.

i use the following command to extract the data.

> cat A7.json | jq '.acList[] | select(.Call | contains("QTR"))' - To fetch Selected airline

But i realized later that the above command only works once. in other words, it does not refresh. as the data is updating every second. i have to execute the command over and over again to extract the filter data which is causing to generate duplicate data.

Can someone help me how to filter the live data without executing the command over and over .

Comment: Have you tried using the `-k -l` combination of nc options?

Comment: Philippe - Can you perhaps articulate what the OP really wants?

Comment: @peak He wants to get a continuous json stream from localhost:30006. But due to buffering, he only see the first result. Which is why I suggested `stdbuf -o 0`.

Comment: @Philippe - So why does OP disallow "nc -k -l ..." ?  Would `tail -f` be of interest?

Comment: @peak from OP's comment to my answer, he has already a server listening on 30006 sending out json stream. `nc -k -l ...` errored with `nc: Address already in use`. `tail -f` would not work on tcp port.

Comment: @Philippe - Obviously he'd have to use nc -k -l with care.  I was thinking that since OS is able to stream to A7.json, it should be possible to have one "nc -k -l" process writing to A7.json in the background, and another process using `tail -f` to read from that file.

Comment: @peak Agreed. Now there is a problem of invalid input. For example, if I have this data `invalid input "valid input"`, is there a way to tell `jq` to ignore `invalid input` and process `"valid input"` ?

Comment: @Philippe - see : Is there a way to have jq keep going after it hits an error in the input file? in the jq FAQ (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Break Down

##### Why I did what I did?

---

- I have live raw json stream data from the virtual radar server, which is running on my laptop along with Kali Linux WSL on the background.
- For those who don't know virtual radar server is a Modes-s transmission decoder that is used to decode different ADS-B Formats. Also, it rebroadcast the data in a variety of formats.. one of them is the Json stream. And I want to save select aircraft data in json format on Kali Linux.
- I used the following commands to save the data before

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 30001 | jq > A7.json - To save the stream.

$ cat A7.json | jq '.acList[] | select(.Call | contains("QTR"))' - To fetch Selected airline
```

- But I realized two things after using the above. One I'm storing unwanted data which is consuming my storage. Two, when I used the second command it just goes through the json file once and produces the data which is saved at that moment and that moment alone. which caused me problems as I have to execute the command over and over again to extract the filter data which is causing me to generate duplicate data.

##### Command worked for me

---

The following command worked flawlessly for my problem.

```
$ nc localhost 30001 | sudo jq --unbuffered '.acList[] | select (.Icao | contains("800CB8"))' > A7.json
```

The following also caused me some trouble which i explain clearly down below.

##### Errors X Explanation

---

This error was resulted in the missing the Field name & key in the json object.

```
$ nc localhost 30001 | sudo jq --unbuffered '.acList[] | select (.Call | contains("IAD"))' > A7.json

#OUTPUT

jq: error (at <stdin>:0): null (null) and string ("IAD") cannot have their containment checked
```

If you see the below JSON data you'll see the missing Field name & key which caused the error message above.

```
{
  "Icao": "800CB8",
  "Alt": 3950,
  "GAlt": 3794,
  "InHg": 29.7637787,
  "AltT": 0,
  "Call": "IAD766",
  "Lat": 17.608658,
  "Long": 83.239166,
  "Mlat": false,
  "Tisb": false,
  "Spd": 209,
  "Trak": 88.9,
  "TrkH": false,
  "Sqk": "",
  "Vsi": -1280,
  "VsiT": 0,
  "SpdTyp": 0,
  "CallSus": false,
  "Trt": 2
}
{
  "Icao": "800CB8",
  "Alt": 3950,
  "GAlt": 3794,
  "AltT": 0,
  "Lat": 17.608658,
  "Long": 83.239166,
  "Mlat": false,
  "Spd": 209,
  "Trak": 88.9,
  "Vsi": -1280
}
{
  "Icao": "800CB8",
  "Alt": 3800,
  "GAlt": 3644,
  "AltT": 0,
  "Lat": 17.608795,
  "Long": 83.246155,
  "Mlat": false,
  "Spd": 209,
  "Trak": 89.2,
  "Vsi": -1216
}
```

##### Commands that didn't work for me.

---

###### Command #1

When i used jq with `--stream` with the filter it produced the below output. `--Stream` with output filter worked without any errors.

```
$ nc localhost 30001 | sudo jq --stream '.acList[] | select (.Icao | contains("800"))' > A7.json

#OUTPUT

jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "acList"
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "acList"
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "acList"
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "acList"
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "acList"
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "acList"
```

###### Command #2

For some reason `-k` `-l` didn't work to listen to the data. but the other command worked perfectly. i think it didn't work because of the existing port outside of the wsl.

```
$ nc -k -l localhost 30001

$ nc localhost 30001
```

`Thank you to everyone who helped me to solve my issue. I'm very grateful to you guys`

Answer (score 0):

As you don't use the `--stream` option, I suppose your document is a *regular* JSON document.

To execute your command every second, you can implement a loop that `sleep`s for 1 second:

```sh
while true; do sleep 1; nc 127.0.0.1 30006 | jq '.acList[] | select(…)'; done
```

To have the output on the screen **and** also save to a file (like you did with `A7.json`), you can add a call to `tee`:

```sh
# saves the document as returned by `nc` but outputs result of `jq`
while true; do sleep 1; nc 127.0.0.1 30006 | tee A7.json | jq '.acList[] | …'; done

# saves the result of `jq` and outputs it
while true; do sleep 1; nc 127.0.0.1 30006 | jq '.acList[] | …' | tee A7.json; done
```

Comment: i've executed the first command like you said .. after that it started showing this `jq: error (at <stdin>:0): null (null) and string ("QTR") cannot have their containment checked` it's doing the same thing like before.. What to do now?

Comment: @Adhithya You could provide some of the contents produced by `nc` to understand why `jq` is failing. Actually, two different outputs would be ideal to see how it changes "live".

Comment: can you explain how to?

Comment: @Adhithya Run `nc 127.0.0.1 30006 | jq > A7.json` as described in your question. Then update your question with the content of `A7.json`. Then repeat running the command (manually) until the new `A7.json` differs from the one you updated the question with, and update your question again. Now you should have two (differing) outputs at two different times, which can be examined by those trying to answer your question. (If finding a differing second one is too tedious, just update your question with one output, but even one would help enormously to find a solution for your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
nc localhost 30006 | tee -a A7.json |
   while true; do
      stdbuf -o 0 jq 'try (.acList[] | select(.Call | contains("QTR")))' 2>/dev/null
   done
```

Comment: i've already streaming data on 30006 port. as the data is not coming from the netcat itself .. it's showing the following thing. 

`nc: Address already in use`

Comment: command-line worked but after 2 seconds it started showing this `jq: error (at <stdin>:0): null (null) and string ("QTR") cannot have their containment checked`

Comment: @Adhithya I added `try` to the jq command.

Comment: The following error is resolved ... `jq: error (at <stdin>:0): null (null) and string ("QTR") cannot have their containment checked`    Turnouts some of the containment are missing in the array..

Comment: Are there other errors/issues ?

Comment: nope.. thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that no other process is competing for the port,  I'd suggest trying:

```
nc -k -l localhost 30006 | jq --unbuffered ....
```

Or if you want to keep a copy of the output of the netcat command:

```
nc -k -l localhost 30006 | tee A7.json | jq --unbuffered ....
```

You might want to use `tee -a A7.json` instead.

Comment: The command didn't work.. it's showing  `jq: error: Invalid numeric literal at EOF at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '....') at <top-level>, line 1:
....
jq: 1 compile error `

Comment: Adhitya - What jq command were you using?  Have you tested it on A7.json independently of nc?  Can you give a sample of the contents of A7.json?

Comment: both the commands you suggested. the output is same

Comment: Adhithya - I did not suggest any specific jq command.  If you really want our help, please respond to ALL the questions: What jq command were you using?  Have you tested it on A7.json independently of nc? Can you give a sample of the contents of A7.json?

Comment: yeah i unknowingly used your command without adding anything to the end which gave the error message.. netcat didn't work with -k -l for me... but the rest of it is perfect.  Thank you